# Play Scala Akka WebSockets change actor path

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, akka

I've followed the example for creating Web Sockets with Scala Play and Akka actors:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWebSockets#Handling-WebSockets-with-Akka-Streams-and-actors

On resume, the controller:

```
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.streams._

class Controller1 @Inject() (implicit system: ActorSystem, materializer: Materializer) {

  def socket = WebSocket.accept[String, String] { request =>
    ActorFlow.actorRef(out => MyWebSocketActor.props(out))
  }
```

And the Actor:

```
import akka.actor._

object MyWebSocketActor {
  def props(out: ActorRef) = Props(new MyWebSocketActor(out))
}

class MyWebSocketActor(out: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case msg: String =>
      out ! ("I received your message: " + msg)
  }
}
```

The actors created (one per websocket connection) are child of /user actor. I've created 3 connections and the actor created were:

1. /user/$b
2. /user/$c
3. /user/$d

I want to change the actors' name based in a field of the web socket message. How could i do this?.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the name of the actor as follows:

1. Create a file BetterActorFlow.scala

   ```
   package your.package

   import akka.actor._
   import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Keep, Sink, Source, Flow}
   import akka.stream.{Materializer, OverflowStrategy}

   object BetterActorFlow {

     def actorRef[In, Out](props: ActorRef => Props, bufferSize: Int = 16, overflowStrategy: OverflowStrategy = OverflowStrategy.dropNew, maybeName: Option[String] = None)(implicit factory: ActorRefFactory, mat: Materializer): Flow[In, Out, _] = {

       val (outActor, publisher) = Source.actorRef[Out](bufferSize, overflowStrategy)
                           .toMat(Sink.asPublisher(false))(Keep.both).run()

       def flowActorProps: Props = {
         Props(new Actor {
           val flowActor = context.watch(context.actorOf(props(outActor), "flowActor"))

           def receive = {
             case Status.Success(_) | Status.Failure(_) => flowActor ! PoisonPill
             case Terminated(_) => context.stop(self)
             case other => flowActor ! other
           }

           override def supervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy() { case _ => SupervisorStrategy.Stop }
         })
       }

       def actorRefForSink =
         maybeName.fold(factory.actorOf(flowActorProps)) { name => factory.actorOf(flowActorProps, name) }

       Flow.fromSinkAndSource(Sink.actorRef(actorRefForSink, Status.Success(())), Source.fromPublisher(publisher))

     }
   }
   ```
2. Use BetterActorFlow instead of ActorFlow:

   ```
   BetterActorFlow.actorRef(out =>
     ChatActor.props(out), 16, OverflowStrategy.dropNew, Some("alicebob"))
   ```

This worked for me. The created actor is at `user/alicebob` (use this with `context.system.actorSelection("user/alicebob")`)

Answer (score 3):

According to the source code of [ActorFlow](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-streams/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/streams/ActorFlow.scala#L38), it is currently not possible to thange the name of the actual actor spawned for a connection (line 38):

```
Sink.actorRef(factory.actorOf(Props(new Actor { ... }) /*, name parameter is omitted */)
```

However, `ActorFlow.actorRef` accepts an implicit `ActorRefFactory`, which is `implicit system: ActorSystem` in all cases in your code. As we know, there are 2 most common ActorRefFactories: `ActorSystem` and `ActorContext`. You can modify your code in such a way that each time a connection is accepted another dummy actor would spawn with your preferred name (e.g. `myActor1`), and pass this new actor's `context` to `ActorFlow.actorRef` instead. In return, actors for connections would be named as follows:

- /user/myActor1/$a
- /user/myActor2/$a
- etc

Comment: Is there a way I can get the actorRef created by `ActorFlow.actoRef` to be created as a child of a specific Actor?

I want to make it so that all websocket actors are children of a master Actor that I can use to coordinate them.