# How do I create WebSockets with Play framework 2.6?

Tags: java, websocket, playframework

I am trying to do the following with Play Framework 2.6:

1. The browser targets the server and a WebSocket is created
2. Later on (after some other request is performed), the servers sends a message to the browser via the WebSocket previously created

Point 1 can be easily done with a route:

```
public WebSocket socket() {
    return WebSocket.Text.accept(request -> {
        // Log events to the console
        Sink<String, ?> in = Sink.foreach(System.out::println);

        // Send a single 'Hello!' message and then leave the socket open
        Source<String, ?> out = Source.single("Hello!").concat(Source.maybe());

        return Flow.fromSinkAndSource(in, out);
    });
}
```

and the WebSocket can be saved server side.

2. But then how can I send data via the WebSocket? (triggered server side)

This was easy to do with 2.5 but the documentation is not very helpful for Play 2.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to implement websocket with help of [Akka actors](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaWebSockets#Handling-WebSockets-with-actors). At first step define actor that will handle messages

```
public class WebSocketActor extends AbstractActor {

    private final ActorRef out;

    @Inject
    public WebSocketActor(ActorRef out) {
        this.out = out;
    }

    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder()
                .match(String.class, message ->
                        out.tell("Sending message at " + LocalDateTime.now().toString(), self())
                )
                .build();
    }

    public static Props props(final ActorRef out) {
        return Props.create(WebSocketActor.class, out);
    }
}
```

This actor will be created per client. `ActorRef out` will send message to connected client. In this example response is send to client on each string message passed to `WebSocketActor`.

Now define API endpoint to open access to websocket for clients. Define ActorFlow that will create new instance of actor on new connection

```
public WebSocket ws() {
    return WebSocket.Text.accept(request -> ActorFlow.actorRef((out) -> WebSocketActor.props(out), actorSystem, materializer));
}
```

According to [source code](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-streams/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/streams/ActorFlow.scala#L40) ActorFlow creates actors with `flowActor` name. So to send message to websockets somewhere in the code we can find actors by their [path](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/general/addressing.html#what-is-an-actor-path-). This will broadcast message to all connected clients

```
actorSystem.actorSelection("/user/*/flowActor").tell("Hello", ActorRef.noSender());
```

Unfortunately I didn't find easy way to change ActorFlow default name but maybe this answer may help you [play-scala-akka-websockets-change-actor-path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37281559/play-scala-akka-websockets-change-actor-path/37441095).

Also you can check [play-java-websocket-example](https://github.com/playframework/play-java-websocket-example) project from playframework examples.